# iBatis Error parsing XML After I moved my code from WebSphere under Windows to WebSphere under AIX

Tags: java, websphere, classloader, aix, ibatis

I am facing an issue while starting my application after I moved my code from WebSphere 7 under Windows to WebSphere 7 under AIX. the error is:

```
Error occurred.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource com/ebla/workflow/integration/frontEndDB/resources/config/sqlmap/companyAnnouncement.xml
```

This is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
        PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
        "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

<sqlMapConfig>
    <settings useStatementNamespaces="true"/>
     <transactionManager  type="JDBC">
        <dataSource type="JNDI">
     <property name ="DataSource" value="JNDI/eserviceDB"/>
</dataSource>
     </transactionManager> 
    <sqlMap resource="com/ebla/workflow/integration/frontEndDB/resources/config/sqlmap/companyAnnouncement.xml"/>
</sqlMapConfig>
```

This is the resource file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Tomcat Settings -->
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//iBATIS.com//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN" "http://www.ibatis.com/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">


<sqlMap namespace="companyAnnouncementSQLMap">
....
</sqlMap>
```

Comment: I have deployed on WebSphere 8.5.5 in AIX and it works without changing anything. Now it is working on WebSphere 7 and 8.5.5 in Windows and WebSphere 8.5.5 in AIX. Most likely it is OS or WebSphere configuration issue. One try to do is to use "url" property of sqlMap instead of "resource" and use an absolute path to specific directory.

Comment: If I have same war file & same AIX but different WebSphere versions and it appears in 7 and not in 8.5.5 then it is a WebSphere issue. either configuration, class loading, etc...